# Import data from dmp

Tags: oracle, import, oracle9i

I want to import some specific tables in a user from dmp file  which were already in my user. I want to replace these table. Any Help

Answer (score 1):

You just can't beat the information given in the Oracle documentation. This chapter should give you everything you need to import your specific tables.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96652/ch02.htm